# how to give path to custom page tpl for content type

Tags: 7, views, theming

I want to give the path for custom page tpl which I have created for specific content type. 'test_insights' is my content type name.I have created custom page tpl in the folder

```
project_name/themes/themename/templates/page--test_insights.tpl.php
```

I want to know how to give the path for created tpl now I tried `http://localhost/project_name/test_insights`

I caught the error as

> The requested page "/project_name/test_insights" could not be found

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for `hook_menu`. You can find the [API here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x).

An Example:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['test_insights'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_test_insights',
      'page arguments' => array(),
    );
    return $items;
  }

//The callback function
function mymodule_test_insights(){
    //Do the necessary actions
    return $something;
}
```

Note: After implementing the `hook_menu` you have to clear the drupal cache to access the URL.

To add content type specific page `tpl` you have to use `theme_hook_suggestions` by implementing [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x). You can add the below code in the `template.php` file of your theme

Example:

```
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) { //themeName change to your theme name
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
  // If the node type is "test_insights" the template suggestion will be "page--test--insights.tpl.php".
   $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. str_replace('_', '--', $vars['node']->type);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm newbiee.can you give some url suggestion to custom page tpl for specific content type

Comment: @user3386779, updated the answer.

Comment: where to write function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['test_insights'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_test_insights',
      'page arguments' => array(),
    );
    return $items;
  }

//The callback function
function mymodule_test_insights(){
    //Do the necessary actions
    return $something;
}

Comment: You have to create a module for that. And inside the .module file you can write it.

Comment: can you give one example

Comment: Refer the drupal [documentations.](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules). Also download and learn the [example module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples). It is well written like a tutorial. Example code is there in the answer itself.

Comment: The second example is the answer for you if it is for a content type. I've added comments in the code and updated the answer. After adding `template_preprocess_page` you have to clear the cache also after creating a new template file.

Comment: i'll try and update you